# What is the explanation of how a LNK file vulnerability (CVE-2015-0096) works?

Tags: windows, security, exploit, penetration-testing, kali-linux

I'm currently doing an assignment that demonstrates the use of CVE-2015-0096. It is also known as 'LNK file vulnerability'. I tried to look it up and got some information (mainly involving .DLL files).

I'm a Mac user and I have very little knowledge about .DLL files which is why I couldn't completely understand this vulnerability and now I'm having a hard time to explain it in my document. What is the simple explanation, considering my weak understanding of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://www.rapid7.com/db/modules/exploit/windows/local/cve_2017_8464_lnk_lpe).

A Windows DLL (dynamically linked library) file is equivalent to a Linux/Mac SO (shared object).

A DLL is a binary file containing libraries.

A LNK file (normal file link) can contain an image preview.

This preview can be a normal image or an image from some specific Windows DLL files.

The problem is that the whitelisted DLL files for that can be bypassed by adding a special header to the LNK file.

Then, the hacker sets the preview to his/her DLL.

When the preview is loaded, the arbitrary DLL file is loaded and you have remote code execution.

Answer (score -2):

CVE-2015-0096 was a security vulnerability that affected Windows operating systems. Specifically, it targeted a certain type of file known as a "shortcut" or ".lnk" file. (Shortcuts are used in Windows to create quick links to files, folders, or programs.)

To simply explain the way it works;
In Windows, you can create shortcut files that point to other files or programs. These shortcut files have the ".lnk" extension. An attacker could create a malicious shortcut file that looked innocent but contained a special payload or instructions. When a user clicks on the malicious shortcut file, Windows would automatically execute the code inside the shortcut file without any warning or confirmation.This code could be designed to do harmful things, such as running malware, infecting the computer, or stealing sensitive information.

The main point here is that this kind of vulnerability allowes attackers to trick Windows into executing code without the user's knowledge or consent, potentially leading to security breaches and system compromises.

Here's a writup on this subject if you wanna learn more; https://www.mcafee.com/blogs/other-blogs/mcafee-labs/rise-of-lnk-shortcut-files-malware/

Hope this helps.