# Where are imported files' class files stored in Java

Tags: java, spring, penetration-testing

I am a penetration tester and I found a path traversal that allows me to access to the WEB-INF folder. I was able to extract web.xml and now I'm trying to download the class files for the application. I was able to grab one referenced in the web.xml. In that code was referenced the following line:

```
import com.SITE.NAME.biz.r.RenderSystemProxy;
```

So naturally, I tried to access:

```
WEB-INF/classes/com/site/name/biz/r/RendersSystemProxy.class
```

But it wasn't accessible. Where might I find the class file for this import?

Comment: You may find it in a jar file inside `WEB-INF/lib` (but it may also be stored somewhere else).

Answer (score 0):

Double-check the package and folder structure to ensure you have the correct path. Typos or case sensitivity issues can cause problems.
But if this does not work look within the WEB-INF/lib directory for JAR files. (This is a common location for packaged libraries and classes.)

Also sometimes the web application might have security mechanisms to prevent direct access to class files, even if you have access to web.xml.

And also you can try to verify that you have the necessary permissions to access the class files in the WEB-INF/classes directory. If the permissions are restrictive, you might need to escalate privileges or find another way to access the files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: @DavidW: It does look like most of [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22599822/haku?tab=answers) are, but there are several language errors in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74880471/ss-and-ps-flag-in-nmap/77142580#77142580) and in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61014840/can-anyone-explain-how-lnk-file-vulnerability-cve-2015-0096-works/77142214#77142214) (contraindications).