# sS and PS flag in NMAP

Tags: networking, port, host, nmap, penetration-testing

I am aware that the -sS flag is for port scanning and -PS is for Host Discovery. But isn't host discovery also a type of port scanning with packets going to some default ports?

What I am trying to understand here is that the command `nmap -sS -p1-10000 SOME_IP` and `nmap -PS -p1-10000 SOME_IP` will produce the same results isn't it, then why do we have different flags at the first place?

Answer (score 0):

`-sS`
If your machine sends an *SNY* packet and receives a response with the *SYN* and *ACK* flags set (open), now your machine  sends an *RST* packet. This scan type reduces scan times.
It also requires **sudo** privileges because it needs to craft raw packets.

`-PS`If TCP Ping is sends a *SYN* or *ACK* packet to a target, if the target reply back with a response the host is up(open).PS denotes a single or a list of ports.

The most notable difference between **-sS** and **-PS** is that **-sS** is  TCP *SYN* scan and **-PS** is TCP *SYN* ping.

Comment: what do you mean by "SYN ping"?

Comment: TCP SYN ping - It indicates that the sender sent a SYN packet to ping a network.              By default, ping scan (-sP) sends TCP SYN or ICMP packets to see if the host is responding. If the firewall blocks the request, the scan will behave as if the host is not active. TCP SYN ping scan, scanning a different port to see if the host is active or not.

Answer (score -1):

-sS is used for TCP SYN scanning (which is primarily a port scanning technique). It sends TCP SYN packets to target ports and observes the responses to determine whether the ports are open, closed, or filtered by a firewall.
It doesn't focus on host discovery but rather on identifying open ports on a host. (Detailed explanation of -sS : https://nmap.org/book/synscan.html)

-PS is used for host discovery (TCP SYN Ping), specifically for sending TCP ping probes to target hosts. It doesn't perform a detailed port scan; its primary goal is to determine whether the host is reachable.
It sends TCP packets to specific ports (Port 80 by default) to check if the host responds, indicating that the host is probably online.
Here's another explanation of how -PS works. (https://hub.packtpub.com/discovering-network-hosts-with-tcp-syn-and-tcp-ack-ping-scans-in-nmaptutorial/)

In your examples:

nmap -sS -p1-10000 SOME_IP would perform a SYN scan on ports 1 to 10,000 of the target host to identify open ports. So it's a full scan.

But nmap -PS -p1-10000 SOME_IP would perform host discovery using TCP ping probes on couple of ports (Like port 80,443 etc.) to check if the host is live. It would not perform a detailed port scan.

So in short terms when -sS used it's a detailed scan with all ports and -PS is for scans on spesific ports quickly.

Hope this helps.